# In Rally SDK 2, how do I update a hash field?

Tags: rally

In Rally SDK 2, how do I update a hash field, like the Author field for a changeset?  I read how to update the Message field, but I can't figure out how to update Author["DisplayName"] hash.

```
var new_message = settings.message;
Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
  type: 'Changeset',
  success: function(model) {
         model.load( '1234', {
              fetch: [ 'Artifacts' ],
              callback: function(result, operation) {
                        if ( operation.wasSuccessful() ){
                            var message = new_message;
                            record.set( 'Message', message);
                            record.save( {
                                callback: function( resultset, operation ) {
                                    console.log( "After saving:", resultset );
                                    if ( operation.wasSuccessful() ) {
                                        var that = tree.ownerCt.ownerCt.ownerCt.ownerCt;
                                        that._getChangesets();
                                    }
                                }
                            } ); 
                        }
               }
         })
  }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

The Author property on Changeset is of type User.  Like any other object associations on Rally's WSAPI you just set this property to the ref of the object you'd like to link.  You set this the same way as you're currently setting Message in your above code snippet.  (Assuming author is writable after the changeset has already been created).

```
record.set('Author', '/user/123456');
```

You can probably also avoid the deeply nested structure of your code a little bit by specifying scope on your callbacks and using member functions in your app definition:

```
_loadChangesetModel: function() {
    //If you already have a changeset record you can get the model
    //via record.self.  Otherwise, load it fresh.
    Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
        type: 'Changeset',
        success: this._onChangesetModelLoaded,
        scope: this
    });
},

_onChangesetModelLoaded: function(model) {
    model.load( '1234', {
        fetch: [ 'Artifacts' ],
        callback: this._onChangesetLoaded,
        scope: this
    });
},

_onChangesetLoaded: function(record, operation) {
    if ( operation.wasSuccessful() ){
        var message = settings.message;
        record.set( 'Message', message);
        record.save( {
            callback: this._onChangesetSaved,
            scope: this
        } ); 
    }
},

_onChangesetSaved: function( resultset, operation ) {
    console.log( "After saving:", resultset );
    if ( operation.wasSuccessful() ) {
        //You shouldn't need to do this now that the scope is correct.
        //I'm guessing 'that' was referring to the app itself?
        //var that = tree.ownerCt.ownerCt.ownerCt.ownerCt;
        this._getChangesets();
    }
},

_getChangesets: function() {
    //refresh
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I just start using Rally last week.  I don't understand why I would get the value for the Author field from a hash map but set it back as a raw text field.  I retrieve the value as follows and it works fine:

author = this.changeset.Author["DisplayName"];

Comment: Objects in Rally's WSAPI are identified by their unique ref: a combination of their type and object id (/defect/1234, /user/3456).  When reading from WSAPI the object you get back for say, Author, will have a _ref property that uniquely identifies it.  These refs are how you update object relationships rather than sending back some other object representation.

Comment: +1 for Kyle's clarification - any attribute that itself points to a Rally object must be specified in Create/Update operations as a ref in the form of the REST url to that object...